# Is there a benefit to using PySimpleGUI's UserSettings over Python's built-in ConfigParser?

Tags: python, settings, pysimplegui

I'm building a PySimpleGui app that needs to read/write configuration settings. Something like:

```
[GUI]
title = My App Name
font_size = 14
font_family = arial
api_key = xxx
```

Python has the built-in [ConfigParser](https://www.pysimplegui.org/en/latest/call%20reference/#usersettings-api-class-interface) class that reads/writes *.ini files but PySimpleGUI has its own [implementation](https://www.pysimplegui.org/en/latest/call%20reference/#usersettings-api-class-interface). Is there an advantage to using PySimpleGUI's settings functionality?

Comment: It simplifies the calls, especially if using JSON files.  In the upcoming PSG5 release, the settings are integrated further into the elements so that values are automatically saved and loaded. If you're a complete beginner you may find the PSG simplified interface more approachable and maybe more likely to use than not use any at all.  The benefit answer is going to depend on the programmer IMO.

Comment: @MikefromPSG Thank you very much. Brand new to PySimpleGUI and like the idea of using PSG's implementation.

Comment: I use JSON files for all my settings/configs.  There are a bunch of examples throughout the demo programs.  The PySimpleGUI calls basically turn JSON files into a dictionry if you use the object interface or a simple pair of function calls for the non-object interface: `user_settings_get_entry` and `user_settings_set_entry`